# Why does $a\cdot \cos(kx)+b\cdot\sin(kx)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin(kx+\phi)$ hold?

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

I've just bought a book to learn how Laplace, Fourier- and z-transformation works and stumbled over

> \begin{align}
>  a_k\cos(kx)+b_k\sin(kx)&=A_k \sin(kx+\varphi_k)\\
> &= A_k[\sin(kx)\cos(\varphi_k)+\cos(kx)\sin(\varphi_k)]
>  \end{align}
>   Equating coefficients leads to
>   $A_k \cos(\varphi) = b_k$ and $A_k \sin(\varphi)=a_k$. It follows:
>   $A_k = \sqrt{a_k^2 + b_k^2}$ and $\tan(\varphi_k) = \frac{a_k}{b_k}$

I understand the part with equating the coefficients and why $\tan(\varphi_k) = \frac{a_k}{b_k}$ is true (because $\tan(\alpha) = \frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\cos(\alpha)}$ if $\cos(\alpha) \neq 0$). But I don't understand how they follow $A_k = \sqrt{a_k^2 + b_k^2}$.

My thought was

\begin{align}
A_k \cos(\varphi) = b_k \land A_k \sin(\varphi)=a_k\\
\Rightarrow (A_k \cos(\varphi))^2 + (A_k \sin(\varphi))^2 = b_k^2 + a_k^2\\
\Leftrightarrow A_k^2 (\cos(\varphi)^2 + \sin(\varphi)^2) = a_k^2 + b_k^2\\
\Leftrightarrow A_k^2 = a_k^2 + b_k^2\\
\Leftrightarrow A_k = \pm \sqrt{a_k^2 + b_k^2}\\
\end{align}

Why is $A_k = - \sqrt{a_k^2 + b_k^2}$ not possible?

Comment: You can use the negative one, but you would need a slightly different $\varphi$ in that case to make it work. Note that $\sin(x) = -\sin(x + \pi)$.

Comment: @KittyL Yes, that seems to be the correct answer as the title of the section is "amplitude spectrum" (and I have never seen a negative amplitude). I am not sure what I should do now with this question. Delete it? Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I think you should keep it for the benefit of future users. I added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. It is possible. But since the goal of this transformation is to write it in the form such that the coefficient represent the magnitude of the wave, they chose the positive number to achieve it.

From mathematical point of view, you can of course choose negative sign. But as Arthur mentioned in the comment, the angle $\phi$ would be a little different.